# How to get dynamic app conf in golang revel

Tags: go, revel

I have project that use `golang-revel` and in my project, i need to connect to 2 databases. Currently, i can migrate the database one by one, but if this project is getting bigger i need to be able to migrate all databases. Is there any way that i can get the database name dynamically in the `app.conf` ?

```
# Settings for database used in GORM Framework
db.automigrate = false
db.driver      = mysql
db.username    = root
db.password    =
db.dbname      = root_database
db.dbname.otherdatabase = other_database_name
db.companies       = other_companies
db.charset     = utf8
db.parseTime   = True
db.loc         =
db.log = true
```

i can migrate by getting db.dbname with `Dbname = r.Config.StringDefault("db.dbname", "")`

But how can i get `db.dbname.otherdatabase` or more database dynamically, so that it can grab all database in the future ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the names in one variable with separator, for simplicity, just use comma

```
db.names = db1,db2,db3,db4
```

Then use `Split` function by `,`

```
temp_db := strings.Split(r.Config.StringDefault("db.names", ""), ",")
```

see [here](https://revel.github.io/manual/appconf.html#custom_properties) for `r.Config.StringDefault` function